# Android: Draw inside a frame determined by a Bitmap in an ImageView

Tags: android, image-processing, canvas

I want to create a window where the user can go out of the borders of the image but the path continues.

I have this code for my Activity

```
public class PaintActivity extends Activity {
PaintView maskView;
ImageView imagen;

Bitmap bitmap;
Bitmap mask;
int bitmapWidth, bitmapHeight;

public int[] getBitmapMinCoords() {
    float[] minCoordF = {0, 0};

    Matrix matriz = imagen.getImageMatrix();
    matriz.mapPoints(minCoordF);

    int[] minCoords = new int[2];
    minCoords[0] = Math.round(minCoordF[0]);
    minCoords[1] = Math.round(minCoordF[1]);

    return minCoords;
}

public int[] getBitmapMaxCoords() {
    float[] maxCoordF = {bitmapWidth, bitmapHeight};

    Matrix matriz = imagen.getImageMatrix();
    matriz.mapPoints(maxCoordF);

    int[] maxCoords = new int[2];
    maxCoords[0] = Math.round(maxCoordF[0]);
    maxCoords[1] = Math.round(maxCoordF[1]);

    return maxCoords;
}



@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.paint);

    imagen = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_paint);
    maskView = (PaintView) findViewById(R.id.mask_paint);

    String imagePath = "/sdcard/images/NewOrleans.gif";

    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath);
    imagen.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

    bitmapWidth = bitmap.getWidth();
    bitmapHeight = bitmap.getHeight();

    ViewTreeObserver vto = imagen.getViewTreeObserver();      
    vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {          
         public void onGlobalLayout() {              
            Matrix matrizTransformacion = imagen.getImageMatrix();
            float[] values = new float[9];
            if (matrizTransformacion != null) {
                matrizTransformacion.getValues(values);
                Log.i(PaintActivity.class.toString() + ".globalListener()", "La matriz tiene valores: " + matrizTransformacion.toString() );
            }

            int[] minC = getBitmapMinCoords();
            int[] maxC = getBitmapMaxCoords();

            Log.i("Listener MinCOORDS (0,0)", minC[0] + ", " + minC[1]);
            Log.i("Listener MaxCOORDS (" + bitmapWidth + "," + bitmapHeight + ")", maxC[0] + ", " + maxC[1]);

            Bitmap mapaBits = Bitmap.createBitmap( bitmapWidth, bitmapHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(mapaBits);

            maskView.layout(minC[0], minC[1], maxC[0], maxC[1]);
            maskView.draw(canvas);
            maskView.refreshDrawableState();

            imagen.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);        
         }      
    });  

}

Bitmap getMaskBitmap(View view) {

    Matrix matrizTransformacion = imagen.getImageMatrix();
    float[] values = new float[9];
    if (matrizTransformacion != null) {
        matrizTransformacion.getValues(values);
        Log.i(PaintActivity.class.toString() + ".onStart()", "La matriz tiene valores: " + matrizTransformacion.toString() );
    }

    Bitmap mapaBits = Bitmap.createBitmap( Math.round(bitmapWidth*values[0]), Math.round(bitmapHeight*values[4]), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(mapaBits);

    int[] minCoords = getBitmapMinCoords();
    int[] maxCoords = getBitmapMaxCoords();

    view.layout(minCoords[0], minCoords[1], maxCoords[0], maxCoords[1]);
    view.draw(canvas);

    return mapaBits;
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.inpainting_color_selection_menu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.inpainting_color_accept_opt:
        ProgressDialog pd = ProgressDialog.show(this, "", "Guardando imagen");

        Bitmap mascara = getMaskBitmap(maskView);


        // GUARDANDO BITMAP EN HDD
        try {
            String filename = "/sdcard/PhotoRestore/mask.png";
            File file = new File(filename);
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
            mascara.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        pd.dismiss();

        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
}
```

This is the code for my PaintView

```
public class PaintView extends View {

    float previousX = -1;
    float previousY = -1;

    float currentX = -1;
    float currentY = -1;

    PaintActivity activity;

    Path path;
    Paint paintLine = new Paint();

    public PaintView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public PaintView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public PaintView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        path = new Path();

        activity = (PaintActivity) getContext();

        paintLine = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        paintLine.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        paintLine.setStrokeWidth(10);
        paintLine.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        paintLine.setAlpha(150);
    }

    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawPath(path, paintLine);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(final MotionEvent event) {

        currentX = event.getX();
        currentY = event.getY();

            switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                path.moveTo(currentX, currentY);
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                path.quadTo(previousX, previousY, currentX, currentY);
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                path.quadTo(previousX, previousY, currentX, currentY);
                break;
            }

            previousX = currentX;
            previousY = currentY;

            postInvalidate();

            return true;

    }
}
```

And this is my XML view

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_paint"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:contentDescription="@string/hola" />

    <com.paint.PaintView
        android:id="@+id/mask_paint"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</FrameLayout>
```

When I push the button I added in the menu I save the image inside memory and the screen continues being there but now i've got a border. Far away this border the paths continues drawing but it's occluded under a black surface and paths are not cutted, that's I want to occur at the beginning of the activity.

I tried to do the same in the 'onCreate()' method of the activity (inside the global layout listener) but it don't runs.

Someone could help me?

First of all, lost of thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the way to solve my problem.
Where I need to put the `view.layout()` is inside the `onDraw()` method of the view that I want to be layout resized.